# jQuery ui Slider for Background and Font Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem regarding my new site design prospect, and it involves using some jQuery and jQueryUI (mainly SliderUi) and some css manipulation.

Everytime I slide the #slider, the width of .left will then update depend on (ui.value from 1-100 + '%'), from here slide + background transition is happening already,
My question is is there any possible way to manipulate the color of texts depending on slider's treshold or value? if yes, can you suggest how can I come up into something like this?
Snippet below.
Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    max: 101,
    min:1,
    value: 51,
    slide: function(event,ui) { 
      var percentage = (ui.value)-1;
      $('.left').css("width",percentage +'%');  
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slider {z-index: 5;background: #666; }
.left, .right {positioackgrn:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100vh;}
.left {background: #000; width: 50%; z-index: 1;}
.right {background: #fff;  z-index: -1; width: 100%;}
.main-content {z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;}
h3 {color: blue; text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="main-content">
  <h3>A part of my font must change color depending on slider-ui threshold</h3>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update!
http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/7od3sfrr/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="left"><h3>My font color must change depending on slider-ui threshold</h3></div>
<div class="right"><h3>My font color must change depending on slider-ui threshold</h3></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left, .right {position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100vh;overflow:hidden;}
.left h3 {color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;width:100vw;}
.right h3 {color: black; text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;width:100vw;}
```

**Original Answer:**
One method to obtain what you are looking for is to pass the slider percentage to a function that can return you an rgb color value. The following page shows how to create rainbows in javascript and I believe can be applied in this case:
http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    max: 101,
    min:1,
    value: 51,
    slide: function(event,ui) { 
      var percentage = (ui.value)-1;
      $('.left').css("width",percentage +'%');
      $('h3').css('color', rgb(percentage));
    }
  });
});

function rgb(p){
    var frequency = .08;
       r = Math.sin(frequency*p + 0) * 127 + 128;
       g = Math.sin(frequency*p + 2) * 127 + 128;
       b = Math.sin(frequency*p + 4) * 127 + 128;
     return  'rgb(' + Math.round(r) + ',' + Math.round(g) + ',' + Math.round(b) + ')';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/376ow969/

Comment: Wow that is nice, I will apply this in some project, but in my case I want to do is, the part with black background must have white fontcolor and part with white background must have black fontcolor, is it possible?

Comment: Ah, your question wasn't clear on that. I've updated my answer with a solution that uses an h3 elements within each of the left and right div elements. CSS is used to mask part of the left element with overflow set to hidden.

Comment: Nice! and just as I thought I must duplicate the elements to create  such thing, well in this case i must use .clone then? thanks Isubi!

Comment: Yes, you could use .clone to duplicate the text and place it where you need it.